# How to match optional group at the end of string with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have the strings like below:

```
(1) Pay for zone 1234 for 1 hour
(2) Pay for zone 4567
(3) Pay for zone 1234 for 1 hour 30 minutes
```

and the following regex (https://regex101.com/r/MBWJUq/1):

```
(\d{4}).*(30 minutes|1 hour(?: 30 minutes)?|(?:[2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour(?: 30 minutes)?)
```

It works well with cases (1) and (3), but doesn't work with case (2). How should I fix it?

It works with case (2), if I make last group optional. But then it doesn't capture first group with cases (1) and (3).

Comment: Perhaps shorted the pattern to include 1 in the range of `[2-9]` and make the part including `.*` optional https://regex101.com/r/pSJZM1/1 `(\d{4})(?:.*((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour(?: 30 minutes)?))?`

Comment: Change the order and add an optional non capture group, https://regex101.com/r/MBWJUq/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the 2 capturing groups and you want to match a range from 1-24 followed by `hour` and optionally a space and 30 minutes, you might shorten the pattern to:

```
(\d{4})(?:.* ((?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour(?: 30 minutes)?))?
```

In parts

- `(\d{4})` Capture **group 1** Match 4 digits (You might prepend a word boundary `\b`)
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `.*`  Match any char 0+ times followed by a space (Or use `.*\b`)
  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour` Match a range 1-24 followed by hour
    - `(?: 30 minutes)?` Optionally match 30 minutes
  - `)` Close group 2
- `)?` Close on capturing group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4kjNn/1)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't change your `pattern` a lot because you didn't explain what you want to extract exactly.

When you make second group optional everything will be consumed by `.*` because it's **greedy**, so you need to fix this first `.*?`.

now the second group should be also put in a `non capturing group` to match either the text ends with something like `for 1 hour` or end of line `\n`.

check this:

```py
import re

text = """
(1) Pay for zone 1234 for 1 hour
(2) Pay for zone 4567
(3) Pay for zone 1234 for 1 hour 30 minutes
"""

RE = r'(\d{4}).*?(?:(30 minutes|1 hour(?: 30 minutes)?|(?:[2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour(?: 30 minutes)?)|\n)'
# same thing using compile with flags MULTILINE
# RE = re.compile(r'(\d{4}).*?(?:(30 minutes|1 hour(?: 30 minutes)?|(?:[2-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]) hour(?: 30 minutes)?)|$)', flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(re.findall(RE, text))
```

OUTPUT:

```
  [('1234', '1 hour'), ('4567', ''), ('1234', '1 hour 30 minutes')]
```